# Bash script - How to make it show status every 3 seconds

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and I want to make it to check up phrase in logs every 3 seconds and when it's done - show success message

I tried to do it so, but I don't see status updating every 3 seconds:

```
until tail -f /path/server.log | grep -i 'Server has started succesfully'
do
 echo Waiting ... '$date'
  sleep 3

done
  echo You are ready '$date'
done
```

Could you please explain to me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `until` loop waits for `grep` to finish.

You probably want something more like

```sh
while true; do
    sleep 3
    echo "Waiting ... $(date)"
done &
pid=$!
 
tail -f test.log | grep -iq --line-buffered 'Server has started succesfully'
kill "$pid"
```

Notice also the addition of the `-q` option for `grep` to avoid having it spill output to the controlling terminal, and the fixed syntax for printing the date. (Single quotes prevent any expansion, so use double quotes; and `$date` is not a defined variable, so I guess you meant to call the `date` command.) The `--line-buffered` option to `grep` may be necessary if the log file only grows slowly.

Demo: https://ideone.com/VK9dW0

Comment: May I do it without Process ID? It shows me error of non-existing PID when I execute the script. Are there any other options (I've just started scripting, so loops are rather hard for me)

Comment: Updated to discard the error message from `kill` when the process is already gone.

Comment: tried the updated code right now - "waiting" loop never ends, even if another terminal tab tail | grep pipeline executed and finished

Comment: I updated to put the `sleep` loop in the background, this is both simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f test|while read; do
 (echo $REPLY|grep -i 'Server has started succesfully') && break
done
```

But you need some kind of additional condition for timeout