# tail -f | grep in if statement

Tags: bash, debian

I'm running from bash script something like

```
$(command -options)&
export SC_PID=$!    
if tail -f <log_filename.txt> | grep --line-buffered -E "(some expression)"; then
        kill -STOP $SC_PID
fi
```

but it's writing `"(some expression)"` in the command line output instead of killing the process. Note that `log_filename.txt` is a log file where's being written output from `$(command -options)` in real time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need `-q` with `grep`

Comment: This code has a num!er of other problems. The command substitution makes no sense. Leaving the process in stopped state almost certainly isn't right; either kill it completely, or leave it alone. The `export` is unnecessary here; it makes the variable available to _subprocesses_ but you have no subprocesses here which want to read it.

Comment: Suspiciously similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491809/bash-script-how-to-make-it-show-status-every-3-seconds - is this homework?

Comment: @tripleee nope, at least mine one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipe (`tail -f ... | grep ...`) will never end.

Add `-m 1` to your GNU `grep` to exit after first match.

Comment: `-q` does the same thing with the additional feature (in this scenario) of not printing the match when it's found.

Comment: @tripleee you're right but the main problem was in not killing the process, so '-m 1' is the solution to this problem

Answer (score -1):

your if statement with "tail -f" can't finished until you break it, so it just can't move to next step. try to split text by lanes, like the following:

```
$(command -options)&
export SC_PID=$!    
tail -f <log_filename.txt)|while read; do
  if (echo "$REPLY"|grep --line-buffered -E "(some expression)"); then
    kill -STOP $SC_PID
  fi
done
```

Comment: The ananlysis is correct but the OP's code has a number of problems. The basic `while read` you added just does (badly and very slowly) what `grep` already does. The parenthese are unnecessary; one of the extra parentheses is a syntax error (I guess you put in more still and then removed only one of them).

Comment: Oh, and the `--line-buffered` option is useless here; you seem to have gleaned it from my answer to the near-duplicate you also answered very similarly.

Comment: --line-buffered is in original script, I just added loop around topicstarter code and it works.